# xpath give empty output using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I am not getting price they give me empty output this is page link [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M0DWQYI?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M0DWQYI)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd


url='https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M0DWQYI?th=1'
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)
item=dict()
try:
    item['price'] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='corePrice_feature_div'] //span[@class='a-offscreen']").text
except:
    item['price']=''
    
print(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for element visibility and then to extract it's text.
The following Selenium code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M0DWQYI'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='corePrice_feature_div']"))).text)
```

The output is

```
$32
98
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to wait for that element to properly load, prior to locating it:

```
[...]
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)


item['price'] = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='corePrice_feature_div']//span[@class='a-offscreen']"))).text
```

Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

EDIT: Here is a complete example of how you can get that information:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t 

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

items = dict()

driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M0DWQYI?th=1')
t.sleep(1)
driver.refresh()
items['price'] = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="corePrice_feature_div"]//span[@class="a-price aok-align-center"]'))).text.replace('\n', '.')
print(items)
```

Result in terminal:

```
{'price': '$32.98'}
```

Comment: again give me empty output...

Comment: Probably Amazon is blocking you after several tries. @developer

Answer (score 0):

You can use bs4 and it will work fine

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

try:
    item['price'] = soup.find('input', id="attach-base-product-price").get('value')
except:
   item['price'] = ''
   finally:
           driver.close()
           driver.quit()
```

print(item)